# Prevent Flood in TcpServer

Tags: sockets, delphi, indy

How i can prevent somebody from flood (send many requisitions to TcpServer)?
i believe they watch the send<->receive from client to server and send a specific packet so much times to server flooding it, per example they send cmdScreenShotData command various and various time creating inumerous files on machine.

This is my OnExecute method:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
type
  PTBytes   = ^TBytes;
  PTIdBytes = ^TIdBytes;
var
  LBuffer     : TIdBytes;
  LProtocol   : TProtocol;
  FTempBuffer : TIdBytes;

  Enviar    : TBytes;
  Protocolo : TProtocol;

  Conexao   : TClientContext;

  procedure AddToMemo(const AStr: string);
  begin
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(AStr);
      end
    );
  end;
begin
  Conexao := TClientContext(AContext);

  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(LBuffer, szProtocol, False);

  LProtocol := BytesToProtocol(PTBytes(@LBuffer)^);

  case LProtocol.Command of
    cmdConnect: begin
      Conexao.Client := LProtocol.Sender;

      if Conexao.Client.HWID = '' then begin
        InitProtocol(Protocolo);
        Protocolo.Command     := cmdHWID;
        Protocolo.Sender.HWID := GeraHWID(40);
        Enviar                := ProtocolToBytes(Protocolo);
        Conexao.Connection.IOHandler.Write(PTIdBytes(@Enviar)^);
        ClearBuffer(Enviar);

        { Seta HWID na conexão }

        Conexao.FClient.HWID := Protocolo.Sender.HWID;

        AddToMemo(Format('[%s] : [%s][%s]', ['Connect', AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP, Protocolo.Sender.HWID]));
      end
      else
      begin
        AddToMemo(Format('[%s] : [%s][%s]', ['Connect', AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP, LProtocol.Sender.HWID]));
      end;
    end;

    cmdDisconnect: begin
      AddToMemo(Format('[%s] : [%s][%s]', ['Disconnect', AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP, Conexao.Client.HWID]));
    end;

    cmdScreenShotData: begin
      AddToMemo(Format('[%s] : [%s][%s]', ['ScreenShotData', AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP, Conexao.Client.HWID]));

      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        var
          LStream : TMemoryStream;
          LPngImage : TPngImage;
        begin
          try
            AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(FTempBuffer, LProtocol.DataSize);

            LStream   := TMemoryStream.Create;
            LPngImage := TPngImage.Create;
            try
              LStream.Write(FTempBuffer[0], Length(FTempBuffer));

              LStream.Position := 0;

              LPngImage.LoadFromStream(LStream);
            finally
              LPngImage.SaveToFile(Format('Screen_%d_%s.png', [GetTickCount, Conexao.Client.HWID]));

              FreeAndNil(LStream);
              FreeAndNil(LPngImage);
              ClearBufferId(FTempBuffer);

              Memo1.Lines.Add('Received screenshot');
              Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('[%s] Pos Screen : [%s][%s]', ['Disconnect', AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP, Conexao.Client.HWID]));
            end;
          except
            FreeAndNil(LStream);
            FreeAndNil(LPngImage);
            ClearBufferId(FTempBuffer);

            Memo1.Lines.Add('Error on Receive ScreenShot');
          end;
        end
      );
    end;
  end;
end;
```

but they send the same packets, i think maybe using WPE Pro i don't know or other flood program to TcpServer.

And it are using so much CPU on machine.

Comment: Use a flood-preventing firewall to limit how many clients can be connected at a time. That is what they are good at.  Once connected, the best you can do at the application layer is limit how fast your server reads new commands from each client.  Also, most of the code you have placed inside of `TThread.Synchronize()` does not actually need to be synced at all, only the `Memo` access does.

Comment: I added the TThread.Synchronize() because if more than one client send screenshot at sametime server freezes, so using a TTHread.Synchronize() solve this issue.

Comment: There is nothing in the code shown that should *freeze* if multiple clients send the same command at the same time without syncing. The only thing I could think of is *possibly* the `TPngImage` handling, but I thought that was thread-safe for local objects? Might just need to use `Canvas.Lock()`, at least. But you don't need to sync the `ReadBytes()` or `TMemoryStream` handling. And you can get rid of `FTempBuffer` and read from the `IOHandler` directly into the `TMemoryStream` using `ReadStream()`, that doesn't need to be synced, either (and you avoid an unnecessary copy of data in memory).

Comment: Without syncing, read the bytes from the `IOHandler` into the `TMemoryStream` and reset its `Position` to 0, then sync ONLY the `TPngImage` and `TMemo` logic. If locking the `TPngImage.Canvas` works during the load+save, then you don't even need to sync the `TPngImage` either, just the `TMemo` (and you already have a function for that piece)

Comment: Otherwise, find a 3rd party thread-safe PNG library so your PNG processing does not have to be UI-bound anymore.  The smaller your syncs are, the faster and safer the code will be.

Comment: The question here it's other, how prevent a flood on TcpServer without use an external program like firewall. The actual code using TThread.Synchronize works perfectly for me.

Comment: "*The question here it's other, how prevent a flood on TcpServer without use an external program like firewall*" - I know, and I already answered that in my very first comment. The server can't prevent outside parties from flooding it with connection requests (DoS attack), you need a firewall or load balancer for that. But once clients are successfully connected to the server, all it can do is limit the speed in which it exchanges data with them. Put a minor sleep after each command that legitimate clients won't notice. Or maybe attach a `TIdInterceptThrottler` to each `IOHandler` connection

Comment: The only other option `TIdTCPServer` has is its `MaxConnections` property, but that is not really meant for flood protection. Or you can `Disconnect()` clients in the `OnConnect` event if they are not allowed to connect (something a firewall should be handling instead). As for the `Synchronize()` issue, I only mentioned that because it is unnecessarily serializing multiple clients and slowing down your processing code.  There is no good reason to sync code that doesn't need to be synced.